# Express $C$ in terms of $A_1, A_2, A_3$ and $A_4$, Homework problem

Tags: probability, statistics, elementary-set-theory

I am taking a bio-statistics class and one of the homework problems as me to Express $C$ in terms of $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$ and $A_4$.

$A_1$ = {mother has influenza}
$A_2$ = {father has influenza}
$A_3$ = {first child has influenza}
$A_4$ = {second child has influenza}
$B$ = {at least one child has influenza}
$C$ = {at least one parent has influenza}
$D$ = {at least one person in the family has influenza}

So I am asked to express $C$ as stated above. My first inclination was to just write $C = (A_1 \cup A_2)$. After some thought I thought this might include intersections of the other sets $A_3$ and $A_4$. So this is what I came up with

$C = (A_1 \cup A_2) - ((A_1 \cup A_4) + (A_1 \cup A_3) + (A_2 \cup A_3) + (A_2 \cup A_4))$

The reason I did this is because I think when I drew it out graphically that it takes care of overlapping probabilities that are not part of $C$.

I am not sure that my logic is correct.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: C can be expressed in terms of {A1}, {A2}, {A1, A2}, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_1\cup A_2$ is correct.

You should not subtract, say $A_1\cap A_4$, because in $A_1\cap A_4$ both the mother and the second child have influenza; then *in particular* it is true that at least one parent has it.

(It is not entirely clear what your notation means when you use all of $\cup$ *and* $+$ and $-$. I'm assuming what you meant was $C = (A_1 \cup A_2) \setminus \bigl((A_1 \cap A_4) \cup (A_1 \cap A_3) \cup (A_2 \cap A_3) \cup (A_2 \cap A_4)\bigr)$).

Comment: Ahhh true, thank you for pointing that out

Comment: I am now saying all of that out loud and it's making good sense now. I appreciate your help and time.